# Visual Studio 2022 - file added in Windows Explorer not recognized by solution or Intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

My csproj file is defined with wildcard .cs file inclusion:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Include=".\**\*.cs" />
```

Is there a correct way to add files in the Windows Explorer, which would refresh the file list?

When I add .cs files in Windows Explorer, they aren't recognized by the solution explorer, even after I close and re-open Visual studio.

This worked in VS2015: closing and opening Visual studio made all new files part of the project, and Intellisense was working, code hilighting, go to definition, find all references, etc...

Not working in 2019 and 2022, but the workaround is to delete the .vs folder. Deleting it seems to reset some cached data, but I also lose a bunch of settings of the project.
(I don't know about VS2017 since I skipped that version).
I also tried to delete just the ".vs/ProjectName/v17/fileList.bin" file, but it doesn't help. I have to delete the ".suo" file as well.

I can add files in the Solution Explorer but that's a more cumbersome than just copy-pasting them between Windows Explorer windows that I have open. Also, it breaks the "include **.cs", since it changes the .csproj file and adds each file as a separate line like so

My workflow includes copy-pasting files from Explorer. Closing and reopening the IDE is annoying, but not such a hassle as deleting the .vs folder and losing all settings.

Also tried with alternative syntax  ("CSFile" xml element instead of "Compile"):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CSFile Include="*.cs"/>
```

But there's no difference in functionality.

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

csproj file: https://pastebin.com/KEeFW4r7

Comment: You could drag the file to the folder in the IDE, it will copy the file to that location and adding it to the project too. Also you could exlude the file and then add it, either by 'Add / Existing item' or drag and dropping.

Comment: Well then the .csproj file gets "broken", the wildcard entry is gone and replaced by a long long list of "<Compile Include=".\FooBar.cs" />" Xml elements. However, I have just played around with adding to the solution explorer, excluding and including files and folders... and it kinda works, I can then revert the .csproj file from repository... could work.

Comment: Please show the complete csproj file. Normally, the easiest way is to use the automatic file inclusion.

Comment: You can try to open the .csproj, include the file in the project with a declaration like this : 
 
<ItemGroup>
           <MyItem Include=”Source\Program.cs”/>
</ItemGroup>
 
If even that doesn't work, can you share your .csproj file code? It is possible that another statement caused the syntax to fail.

Comment: I've uploaded the contents of the .csproj file to https://pastebin.com/KEeFW4r7  ... Thanks for the replies so far. I figure if nobody can see the problem by a quick glance, I will recreate the csproj file from scratch and see up until which point it still works.

Comment: If you confirm that the relevant cs files have been introduced, usually the reason for not being recognized may be that the classes or variables in the referenced cs files have problems with their modifiers. Usually what we need is a public access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, there were two issues at the same time.

1. The first, some folders were prefixed with the @ symbol, like @Connections. After renaming those folders to remove the @, I no longer have to "Clean Solution" or delete the ".vs" folder after adding a file to that folder. I noticed this solution since for folders that don't have an @ prefix, it wasn't an issue, except for the sluggish performance, solution to which which is described below.
2. The other was just very slow and sluggish performance of visual studio, it's a very large codebase. I have disabled some of the more recent IntelliSense functionality, I forgot which exact option made it work much faster all the sudden, I think it was Options -> TextEditor -> C# -> Advanced -> uncheck Run code analysis in separate process